Goland not stopping at breakpoint when debugging
I have a Mac M3 and I'm using Goland 2024.1.4 and I'm using Go 1.21.12 Darwin ARM64 from this link https://go.dev/dl/go1.21.12.darwin-arm64.pkg.
When I run go env GOARCH GOOS I get
go env GOARCH GOOS
amd64
darwin

My GOHOSTARCH is arm64
I changed the GOARCH using the commando export GOARCH=arm64
I'm trying to use debug in my Goland. But it doesn't stop in the breakpoint.
I tried to install the dlv using this command
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
But it installs in this folder name darwin_amd64 which looks odd.
My issue is that it is not stopping in the breakingpoint when running in debug.
Edit 1 -----------------
Running file $(which go)
I get this
/usr/local/go/bin/go: Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64
Edit 2 -------
Here is a gif of running the debug and not stopping at the breakingpoint


Do you have some other x86_64 build of Go installed that takes precedence in $PATH?

What does file $(which go) print?

Could you please try to invoke go env GOARCH GOOS in a GoLand terminal (View | Tool Windows | Terminal)? Does it produce the same result? Is Settings | Go | GOROOT has the same value as a local terminal?
